# Assertion error when using StreamProvider in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use provider package in my flutter app. In order to access user location, I created *LocationProvider* class that has a stream of location data inside. I want my child widget to access this location data, so I used *StreamProvider.value()* method. However it doesn't work and returns *Failed assertion: 'builder != null': is not true*. I don't why it keeps failing because builder is required in **StreamProvider()** not **StreamProvider.value()**.

```
class LocationProvider extends StreamProvider {
  final Location location = new Location();

  Stream<LocationData> get currentLocation =>
      location.getLocation().asStream();

}
```

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
        child: new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sharify',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: new ToolMap(),
      ), stream: LocationProvider().currentLocation,
    );
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
I/flutter (29561): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (29561): The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: AppState#95d57):
I/flutter (29561): 'package:provider/src/adaptive_builder_widget.dart': Failed assertion: line 10 pos 16: 'builder !=
I/flutter (29561): null': is not true.
I/flutter (29561):
I/flutter (29561): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (29561): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (29561): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (29561):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (29561):
I/flutter (29561): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (29561): #2      new AdaptiveBuilderWidget 
package:provider/src/adaptive_builder_widget.dart:10
I/flutter (29561): #3      new StreamProvider 
package:provider/src/stream_provider.dart:40
I/flutter (29561): #4      new LocationProvider (package:sharify/tool_list/providers/location_provider.dart)
I/flutter (29561): #5      AppState.build 
package:sharify/main.dart:48
I/flutter (29561): #6      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3825
I/flutter (29561): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3739
I/flutter (29561): #8      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3565
I/flutter (29561): #9      BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2278
I/flutter (29561): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:700
I/flutter (29561): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:286
I/flutter (29561): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1012
I/flutter (29561): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:952
I/flutter (29561): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:773
I/flutter (29561): #16     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (29561): #17     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (29561): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Comment: @pskink updated

Comment: why do you  need `class LocationProvider extends StreamProvider`? why it has to extend `StreamProvider`? all you need is a `Stream` returned directly from `location.getLocation().asStream()` - i mean `stream: location.getLocation().asStream()`

Comment: @pskink It works if I delete the extends StreamProvider. But I don't know if I'm loosing some benefits (listening to events, notifying widgets) from provider package this way.

Comment: no, you just need `@required Stream<T> stream`, see [StreamProvider.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider/StreamProvider.value.html) - this is `StreamProvider` in the `build` method that listens, notifies and builds child widgets